# Wildcard property name in interface?

Tags: typescript

I know you can set a complete wildcard on an interface to allow any property you want in like:

```
interface ITest {
    [wildcard: string]: any;
}
```

But is there a way to have a wildcard match a pattern for the property name?

```
interface ITest {
    /EndOfKeyName$/: boolean;
    /^startOfKeyName/: string;
}
```

It doesn't have to be regex, I'm just trying to show an ideal scenario. I'm not sure this is possible though.

Comment: What would you want to have happen for my key `startOfKeyNameAndEndOfKeyName`?

Comment: @JeffBowman It's mostly just about having intellisense for that key. I use JSDoc comments a lot, so it's just for documentation if a key were to match.

Comment: @m0ngr31 Potentially possible with template literal types? \`startOfKeyName${string}\`: string; or similar

Comment: @LoganDevine, I've tried that: `'string' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.`

Comment: That's odd.. You are doing `interface ITest { <template literal>: string; }`?

Comment: ```interface ITest { `start${string}`: string; }```

Comment: what about ```[key: `start${string}`]: string;```?

Comment: `An index signature parameter type must be either 'string' or 'number'`

Comment: (I'd been writing a partial answer, that converged over time with this comment thread. Leaving as a community wiki tombstone to save other answerers the trouble of trying. This one might be beyond Typescript's capabilities, sorry!)

Comment: You can do [this](https://tsplay.dev/4w1jyN), as in the answer to [the linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65878880/typescript-template-literal-as-interface-key). Don't think you can get IntelliSense though, even so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**UPDATE FOR TS 4.4:** Template Literal Types can now be used as below, as in [the duplicate answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65879197/1426891). The functionality is documented as ["Symbol and Template String Pattern Index Signatures"](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-4-beta/#symbol-template-signatures).

```js
interface BoolsAndStrings {
    [key: `boolean${string}`]: boolean;
    [key: `string${string}`]: string;
}
```

[typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.4.0-dev.20210702#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEIHt0BsDOBBEAEwGUwpQBzHZAbwFgAoZZ5AbQGsIBPALmQAMARpiwQ4IACQ0cZSgF9+AXT7DsYkAG5GLNp14CZ5EBSmH5SvmeNaGcoA)

If you attempt this in TypeScript 4.3 or prior, it will yield:

> An index signature parameter type must be either 'string' or 'number'

Comment: Thanks Jeff, unfortunately it looks like I'm out of luck for now

Comment: @m0ngr31 Good news, Typescript 4.4 is in beta, and it supports your request now. See [the accepted answer in the duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65879197/1426891).