# Mapped types and string litterals

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to use mapped types and string litterals together and eveything kind of works except for one thing. The "out" type (after the ":") of my mapped types is not used, it's replaced by unknown.

Here is a [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PQKgsAUAsghgDnApgEwAQBcCeSDOqYB2aO6ATgJYEDmqANueuoqTLTpJAJIDkAthqUyUa6APaoArjkSpe8JGiy58RVCQrU6DJizYZRVROgAWzFWkQA3RJhPDUAa0ppRAM1QB3UaQd5EADwBjRDh0VFdvVFECGTtqADpUABVTVAAiUQl0NIxsGQAKGFcdDFS0gC40gEoo915MWXkUXOVyPAJRMKkUABpUBm48UhDaGGC0ACMGiQIHDo8CeMgQYA4ISh1XMZlYOAAlGA9UAG9IVHP0khh0KQrUAgleCeYes4u08mREAnQGTE5kHd1MJXhAAL5rJQ7eAAMW8e0QgW8yHsAF4Tm9zgBtAAK-QIqAABsMkaQUQkACTHYHUMGEgC65VQE1EoloiEIkAhEEgUNQACFyFRdqh0bsDkcAGSoXZw0gI0nkqgAbjWrhmgV%200TURgAPElUAEmEQ8A4bG4BULdgA%20fJmzBMpJ9SysCSIAD8TMFwvgWKS9KqTMsok%20J1Q3PVBE15G1hnQ%20sN-mNyFN5vc3ptdpsjr6Xy2Elo6AAaq7EF6rb7-agAD73Au0UV12i0QOWn1wP30sPDG6kAkPZsAQnDa3ZYRJyOEADkYLwZOi0jA0srUMBgKU2p5MrQ0B0ws81OhruRAvjSjIxjdWKgkV9mVlUCwiKJeLQGoYYiwmMhINJ0Pk0iuG4cDSPoAEYqhXNcogcPoAiQTUUF-IwAKA24%20kXaooPXZhSEiZ5AhgboZXgCV4jQvBNxgQ8NCoOD-AQ79kP-YlEUnSljgnMlp1nRA6XwPAkQIEg%20jIN1INXddRFgxNGKQiA-wA0xm1EHIYEE6IRIEcTsMNUg8NIZlESI6R0mU2hVNQZBREQHACG4MIrlIMIPAYYx0i4pV4lA2TESYnkIDHfBGzjfJWMVYR4ipTyeLnfj1JvTT0Ak6DqM3C0%20RmOZRAWPopwAeQNABRAANHEioAYSSIqABE%20k4LcCzQegzWCsQjNqFoZBZNkOQINZQEgAAJHLEqa1AGrjIkYEJTw3K65lWXZQh3WWYAgA) with the code.

```js
interface MapRaw {
    "status": number,
    "identityId": string,
}

type MapForRecording = {
    [P in `recording.${string}`]: boolean
}

type BigMap = MapRaw & MapForRecording;

function set<T extends keyof BigMap>(key: T, value?: BigMap[T]): void { }
function get<T extends keyof BigMap>(key: T, defaultValue: BigMap[T] | null = null): BigMap[T] { return null! }

let recordingName = "a"; // this would not be static in the actual code but randomly generated
set("status", 1); // ok, expected
set("status", "a"); // error because MapRaw.status is a string, expected
set(`recording.${recordingName}` as const, true); // ok, expected
set("hello" as const, true); // error because "hello" doesn't start with "recording.", expected

let a = get(`recording.${recordingName}` as const); // a is of type unknown, NOT EXPECTED, I would like a to be of type boolean
```

How could I get `a` with type boolean?

Comment: Using string template literal types as index types seems to just not be supported; for example, if you hover over `MapForRecording` then it says this type is just `{}`, and if you declare `type Test = MapForRecording[keyof MapForRecording]` then it gives an error ``Type '`recording.${string}`' cannot be used as an index type``. If you declare `type ValueOf<T> = T[keyof T]` then `ValueOf<MapForRecording>` is `unknown`.

Comment: You can't use "pattern" template literals as keys in TypeScript; see the [question this duplicates for info and how to work around it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65878880/typescript-template-literal-as-interface-key).  You can do [this](https://tsplay.dev/WJ9Agm) instead for your case, where you replace the lookup `BigMap[K]` with a conditional type `BigMap<K>`.