# Typescript: allow any property starting with a specific string

Tags: typescript

I need to assign properties with unique names, all starting with a string, say `meta_`.

How do I write a type for this?

```
type MyType = {
  knownProp: string,
  [key: TypeForAnyStringThatStartsWithMeta_]: string, // how to define a type to use here?
}
```

Comment: Note: when TS4.4 ships, you'll be able to do [this](https://tsplay.dev/Nn6JeN).

Answer (score 1):

For TS4.4+, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65879197/2887218)

---

TS4.3- answer:

You can use [template literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#template-literal-types) with *patterns* in them, as implemented by [microsoft/TypeScript#40598](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/40598), to represent strings of that form:

```
type AllowedKeys = `meta_${string}`

function foo(k: AllowedKeys) { }

foo("meta_okay") // okay
foo("not_okay") // error!
// Argument of type '"not_okay"' is not assignable 
// to parameter of type '`meta_${string}`'.
```

---

*Unfortunately*, you can not currently define an object type using pattern template literals as keys.  You would like to be able to write something like:

```
type Oops = Record<AllowedKeys, unknown>;
// type Oops = {}
const hmm: Oops = { meta_okay: 123 }; // fine, but
const oops: Oops = { not_okay: 123 }; // NO ERROR!  uh oh
```

but as you see it doesn't work.  The compiler merely ignores any such template literal keys in [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html).  See [microsoft/TypeScript#42192](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/42192) for more information.  This may eventually be addressed, but I'm not sure.

---

That means there is currently no *specific* object type which behaves the way you want.  As a workaround, you could write a [*generic*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type that represents a *constraint*, and then use a helper function to validate potential candidates:

```
type ValidObj<T> = { [K in keyof T]: K extends AllowedKeys ? T[K] : never };
const asValidObj = <T extends ValidObj<T>>(t: T) => t;

const okay = asValidObj({ meta_okay: 123, meta_also_okay: 456 });
const notOkay = asValidObj({ meta_okay: 123, not_okay: 456 }); // error!
// ----------------------------------------> ~~~~~~~~
// Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'never'.
```

So instead of being able to write `const obj: ValidObj = {...}`, you have to write `const obj = asValidObj({...})` instead.  Until and unless microsoft/TypeScript#42192 is addressed, this is probably the best you can do.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.2.3#code/C4TwDgpgBAggNnA9gdwgEwNIRAZygXigAMBbCYAQwH0ASAbx2ACcBLAOwHMBfIgKF4BmAVzYBjYC0RsoAxIgAUAawBcsBCnRZcASih0oXfrIUAiMpSqJFFECd0B6e1Cs3Bc+SbaJgl67YdOEExMiEwAhLyOsEwcQmRswM4CUKCQUADknt6+NibpUCx4XokUODgsHGwUAEZw0MCIUGAUTBTmQUkp4NDppOTU9IysnDzpAHT8qdAA8ohgeIQAShCioWgAPPBIqJjYOAA0UCKKXshsAHwA3JFOU1Cz8wR6hqtsjFAAFiQkqg8LelBzNQXCBVABGABMAGYDJcoFEBOwIIdqkJgLxXu85PNfnN-vpijlQVBITCuHCogA5aZQACii0W00WYSgRw+zg+-F4dwAahQ4Cw0NNqgArdYAFXOT30AG0MAVpIpsIhkuKALqqeUQAAewAgbDQeC2Gl2uCgAH4oOK5WqoKo2BAAG4dckYqTvUp8gVC0VPCVQHV6g14L2C4ViyXneTAVTi3T4KXAa5ut6JEFPT38sOi+T6IFE8HQw75-k4RAFqAAFgArAA2Azaa6YxLFaZ+DM4UM+kW5wH9Cukw6EkGqGv1riN+GBYKhCJRAC0i6Xy5Xq7X6+XUoAfjvdzublbuhk2HFqkF8oUoMUoKVypUanUUo07ukHc6mOMgA)

Comment: What if Typescript is before 4.0? An expression like this `type AllowedKeys = `meta_${string}`` won't be allowed.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this from 4.1 and it's about as close as you can get

```
type MetaMatch = `meta_${string}`

const foo : MetaMatch = "meta_hello_world" //ok
const bar : MetaMatch = "hello_world" // error
```

Comment: Tried to use this as follows: `type MarkedText = {[key: MetaMatch]: string}` and TS gives two errors: "TS1110: Type expected" and "TS2693: 'string' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here."

Comment: You need `key in` for a mapped type. But look at @jcalz's answer, it gives a more thorough example of how to use this in a type-safe way. With a generic + helper.