# Typescript string type that must start with specific characters

Tags: typescript, types, typechecking

I know in TypeScript we can enforce specific strings like so:

```
const myStrings = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'] as const;
type MyStringTypes = typeof myStrings[number];
```

However, what I would need is to enforce only the first characters of my final strings.

For instance, I would like to create a type (`MyPrefixTypes`) with something like `'prefix1'`, `'prefix2'`, ..., `'prefixN'`, followed by any other character.

Using this, I would be able to check if the string is correct or not.

Example:

```
const foo: MyPrefixTypes = 'prefix1blablabla'; // OK
const bar: MyPrefixTypes = 'incorrectprefixblablabla'; // NOT OK
```

Answer (score 68, accepted):

As of TypeScript 4.1, you can use a [template literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html) for this.

```ts
type StartsWithPrefix = `prefix${string}`;
```

This works for type unions as well:

```ts
// `abc${string}` | `def${string}`
type UnionExample = `${'abc' | 'def'}${string}`;

// For your example:
type MyPrefixTypes = `${MyStringTypes}${string}`;

const ok: UnionExample = 'abc123';
const alsoOk: UnionExample = 'def123';
const notOk: UnionExample = 'abdxyz';

// Note that a string consisting of just the prefix is allowed
// (because '' is assignable to string so
// `${SomePrefix}${''}` == SomePrefix is valid)
const ok1: MyPrefixTypes = 'foo'
const ok2: MyPrefixTypes = 'barxyz'
const ok3: MyPrefixTypes = 'bazabc'
const notOk1: MyPrefixTypes = 'quxfoo'
```

You can even define a helper type:

```ts
type WithPrefix<T extends string> = `${T}${string}`;

type StartsWithPrefix = WithPrefix<'prefix'>;
type UnionExample = WithPrefix<'abc' | 'def'>;
type MyPrefixTypes = WithPrefix<MyStringTypes>;
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAFwngDgpgBA6gSxACwAoCcoDMEA8A8AKjFLiFAHYAmAzjDSOghQOYB8MAvDAAYAkAb0IBfQQyathPANzBgAYwD2FBjAC2YAMqNmLOtwDaAciyLFRgDQwjAIwCG6S9fsAvIwF0YdukpUhZ4NAwALJaOqyEkFD6MIFQiljqYRJ6BhQArmo2UOjussAA9AWxUTDaDiA0iCgY2HhcvBCYOLhi4SxSAaXl6JXVaM313P21LfhGTXW4Rmz5vqqmigBcZSAVVUgDUw0Tg7gAjDYANnbHpydG0jBFMADyANIKyqr26Cs9fZujQ9bMSuiYeQgSYtM5gi5XG4AOVuxAechucRgAFUKAhlABRXB2NQQI6wbj8ARGU7yIwwAA+1io2CMogE4l0nVApVR6IoWJxeIJ8C+e3GpPJVKMNKwMzmzxAMEUAGsVmzMdjcfidqT9gAmADMlyefi8RxoilucpRaMVXJV3BF2A12tk8ylFEUIGN8rNHKV3NVNiouDAbnyiNKoW+uEi0BiRNC2hS4ei9MZkhkLKCIb2cZiI350faGdmcgd0pl+xWaamGZ2iyMutUsvVpbAoYrVtefrcNalss1DabURitjsLkFHZgTpdxZ76b7OwAjulcFXgEA)

---

Related:

- [typescript template literal as interface key](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65878880/8289918)
- [Typescript: allow any property starting with a specific string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67232587/8289918)

Comment: Great, thanks! Would you mind making an example that would work with multiple prefixes as in my case? I don't know exactly how to combine thiswith `typeof`.

Comment: Unions work the same way! See my updated answer.

Comment: last question (of course, feel free to ignore it): how would I use it with `as const` and `typeof` as in my example (if possible)?

Comment: You've already figured out the tricky part in defining `MyStringTypes`. All you need to do is use `${MyStringTypes}${string}` :)

Comment: If you're using Typescript before 4.1, is there no way to specify string type that starts with specific characters?

Comment: @bytrangle No, I don't believe there is a way to do that, unfortunately.

Comment: For the record, `prefix${number}` is also valid, for anyone wanting to type a variable which is a prefix followed by numbers