# Set a manipulated primitive type (string) as an index signature in Typescript

Tags: typescript

#### Issue

I want to create a type that can accept only specific keys (e.g "dog" | "cat") AND every other string that starts with `_` (`'_{string}'`). For example:

```js
const results = {
    cat: true,
    dog: true,
    
    // SHOULD WORK
    _fish: true,
    
    // SHOULD BE INVALID
    invalid: false,
}
```

#### My use case

I have a table component that accepts `columns` object prop that can be either a property of a row (e.g firstName) or a computed property (e.g `_actions`)

#### See [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAggdgSwLYEMA2UC8UBEATAewHMcoAfXAYxWBwG4BYAKFEigFU48IAnAZ0oEeEAMrAeCOESxQABgH0AJAG8%204yUQC%20sxi3DR4ydAHUEwABadu-QcLESpfGcuZQ3UANoBrCCCiTYRFQMCiteASFRdSkAXQAuKAAjAgI0CBQ4XU1mZgB6XKgAeQBpZkE4NSgUBLCbSPsNGRx5PgIkCAsNehymfKgAAWA%20AFoIAA9ISmBRnh4hIq8yggrgJJqucNsoh2lsHFb2zqlupiWVqGE%20AFc0IYTDYNMLWoi7aKInbBcmdyhqYAS4iuEAANK53IQiICeMCwT93OC3H0RAAJQrsAAyABEoMZCgAlUrwtzyABmCD45mhsMRUFpyLRmJxACEAKJQACSADkAGowDEcrG0yQAN3QCDwCVJ6D4oOYmiAA)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typescript 4.4 introduces [Symbol and Template String Pattern Index Signatures](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-4-beta/#symbol-template-signatures) that seems to resolve my issue. [See playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.4.0-dev.20210701#code/C4TwDgpgBAggdgSwLYEMA2UC8UBEATAewHMcoAfXAYxWBwG4BYAKFEigFU48IAnAZ0oEeEAMrAeCOESxQABgH0AJAG8%204yUQC%20sxi3DR4ydAHUEwABadu-QcLESpfGcuZQ3UANoBrCCCiTYRFQMCiteASFRdSkAXQAuKAAjAgI0CBQ4XU1mZgB6XKgAeQBpZkE4NSgUBLCbSPsNGRx5PgIkCAsNehymfKgAAWA%20AFoIAA9ISmBRnh4hIq8yggrgJJqucNsoh2lsHFb2zqlupiWVqGE%20AFc0IYTDYNMLWoi7aKInbBcmdyhqYAS4iuEAANK53IQiICeMCwT93OC3H0RAAJQrsAAyABEoMZCgAlUrwtzyABmCD45mhsMRUFpyLRmJxACEAKJQACSADkAGowDEcrG0yQAN3QCDwCVJ6D4oOYmiAA)

Answer (score 1):

The type of `AnimalWithUnderscoreStrings` in the original playground is statically determined at the declaration site, which you can see by hovering the type: the `_${string}` key is not there at all.

What you can do is create a function that constrains the input to the given key requirements:

```
type AnimalWithUnderscoreStrings<K extends PropertyKey> = {
    [key in K]: key extends Animal | UnderscoreString ? boolean : never;
}

const asAnimalWithUnderscoreStrings = <K extends PropertyKey>(
    obj: AnimalWithUnderscoreStrings<K>
) => obj;

const results = asAnimalWithUnderscoreStrings({
    cat: true,
    dog: true,
    
    // SHOULD WORK
    _fish: true,
    
    // SHOULD BE INVALID
    invalid: false,
})
```

This works by inferring the set of keys passed in the object to `asAnimalWithUnderscoreStrings`, and thus is able to constrain them to include ones with underscores.

Comment: Interesting why it works. Can you elaborate more on this?

Comment: Elaborated the answer a bit further. There's also this post which may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65879197/13065068