# TypeScript Typing object keys made out of string concatenation with numbers

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I seem to be missing something in TypeScript. Basically, I have an Array of object I get from an api and the object interface can be represented as followed:

```ts
    interface ResponseObject {
       title: string;
       description: string;
       image_1: string;
       image_2: string;
       image_3: string;
       ...
    }
```

The amount of images received can vary depending on the response and I can have a object with 2 images, one with 50. Is there a way to avoid typing all potential image use case and have a Custom TypeScript Type that would have the image keys be a string concatenated with any number. `image_<number>`?

*My apologies for the TS formatting in the post, did not find the way to have the TS syntax highlighting*

Comment: There is a type like `\`image_${number}\``, but unfortunately it cannot be used as a key type (as of TS4.3).   So you need a workaround like [this](https://tsplay.dev/WJ9Elm), which is explained more in the answer to [the linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65878880/typescript-template-literal-as-interface-key)

Comment: If you don't mind picking some reasonable upper limit on the number of `image_XXX` properties, you can do something like [this](https://tsplay.dev/w26YVw) instead, where we make the compiler enumerate the keys from 1 to (say) 249 and make them all optional properties

Comment: Ok I see. As far as I understand there will be something called arbitrary signature available in TS 4.4 that that might solve these specific issues. For now, the solution you provided could work on my use case. Thans a lot for that !!!

Comment: They have pushed back arbitrary index signature a few times so I don't know if it'll actually make into 4.4 or it will be bumped again.

Comment: Instead of creating multiple array types with dummy data in it, is there another way to have one type simulating an Array of X elements ? I am refering to the solution you provided [here](https://tsplay.dev/w26YVw)

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "simulating an Array of X elements".

Comment: Instead of creating the Foo, Bar Baz variables in your example, I was wondering if there is a less "hacky" way to create a filled array of length